# Android EditText separates the cursor position from the water droplet position after scaling the Framelayout layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, editor

Here is the demo Images：
Before
[image: beforeScale]
After
[image: afterScale]

Android EditText separates the cursor position from the water droplet position after scaling the Framelayout layout

As mentioned in the question, I added an EditText to a scalable Framelayout. When zooming in on the FrameLayout, the EditText followed suit, but the position of the selected EditText droplet was incorrect. Normally, it needs to be below the cursor.

Here is the code：

```
public class ScaleFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private float scale = 1;

        public ScaleFrameLayout(Context context) {
            this(context, null, 0);
        }
    
        public ScaleFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }
    
        public ScaleFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new     ScaleListener());
        }
    
        public void setScale(float scale) {
            this.scale = scale;
            invalidate();
        }
    
        public float getScale() {
            return this.scale;
        }
    
         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.scale(scale, scale);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =   (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
                    this.setScale(mScaleFactor);
                    this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    this.invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private class ScaleListener extends   ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.3f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.5f));
            
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to make the water droplet position correct？